# Reading/writing files line-by-line reporting position

Tags: java, io

I wish to read and write some files line-by-line.

My first thoughts were to use `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` but my gotcha is that I need to know how far through the files I am.

When reading I would like to who how far through processing the file I am and I would like it to be accurate, so after every `readLine()` I am expecting the position to update, this is complicated by the fact that there is a buffer involved.

Same applies to writing, I need to get the position accurately before and after writing a line. I'm guessing this isn't as difficult as my understanding is that a BufferedWriter flushes after every newline char anyways, so given that I am writing lines, I could just write straight to the channel.

Before I reinvent the wheel here, or use some dodgy reflection, is there anything in the JDK that can help me out here?

**EDIT:** Just to clear things up, I am looking for byte positions.

Comment: Is [`java.io.LineNumberReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) useful?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't entirely clear based on your question what you mean by "how far through processing the file I am". Does that mean line number or byte position?

If it means line number, there are really two options:

A) Keep a track of the line numbers manually. Shouldn't be that hard. Just increment a counter for every line.

B) Use [java.io.LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) as suggested by @Jesper

If it means byte position, increment the byte position counter by each line length and don't forget to include the newlines in the byte position as well.

When writing, there is no LineNumberWriter so you need to keep track of the counters manually. Shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Well, then LineNumberReader doesn't help. I recommend keeping a byte position counter and incrementing it by the line length (including the newline!) as you read lines, and do the same for writing. Yes, it requires some manual coding but shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: The main thing I am worried about is charset and `\n` vs `\r\n`...I reckon it will be quite difficult to get right which is why I was hoping for something "out-of-box"

Comment: Yes, you are correct in worrying about `\n` vs `\r\n` and charset. You could implement your own variant of BufferedReader that keeps track of the number of _characters_ read, but that won't help for _bytes_. And accessing the underlying InputStream won't help as BufferedReader does buffering. This doesn't seem to be so easy after all...

Answer (score 0):

see below example for reading file using RandomAccessFile

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class ConsoleReader {

   /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("fileName");
       try {
           RandomAccessFile r = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
           //First time read
           String str = null;
           while((str = r.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
           }
           r.seek(r.getFilePointer());
           startTimer(r);
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
    }

    private static void startTimer(final RandomAccessFile r) {
     Timer timer = new Timer();
     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
     String str = null;
     try {
          while((str = r.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(str);
          } 
          r.seek(r.getFilePointer()); 
     } catch (IOException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
      }
 }, 0, 1000);
    }
}
```